# How to implement friend system for Wordpress?  

Tags: users, author

At the moment my users posts are only viewable to them. I would like to implement a system where they can choose to share any post with other users they know. The problem I'm having is, how do I make the connection between users?

The best I came up with is to create a table in the db and store their friends by user id's. 
Example:

```
user_ID 2   friends_ID 5,9,34,85

user_ID 87   friends_ID 67,2,99,100,58,309
```

I want to be able to retrieve their friends list so I can use it later in various parts of the site.

I know this will not be simple, but I am fully open to ideas, suggestions or similar plugin.  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think you're asking for quite a lot of code here. Either break it down, and ask questions along the way, or you could consider wpquestions.com to pay someone to do it!!

Comment: I am not asking for code, I am asking how would you go about setting up the friends in the db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BuddyPress can be used as a framework - it allows you to friend other users, and is a good place to start from.

[Update]

This is the structure of the BuddyPress friends table (bp_friends)

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_bp_friends` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `initiator_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `friend_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_confirmed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_limited` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `initiator_user_id` (`initiator_user_id`),
  KEY `friend_user_id` (`friend_user_id`)
);
```

Comment: That's available at http://buddypress.org, FYI, or just search on BuddyPress in the plugin installer inside of WordPress itself.

Comment: Thank for your suggestions anu & ZaMoose, but I have considered using Buddypress and it has many features I don't want and it will need to be heavily modified to work with my already existing sits. Instead of modifying Buddypress and mysite I can take the time to build a system myself and get all the features I need. I am just look for ideas on the best way to store the data as I have little experience working with databases.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the structure of the BuddyPress friends table

Comment: Thank you again anu. I was just about to dig through BP to see how they are doing it. Thanks.